# extjs pie chart all legend showing same color

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, legend

I am using extjs 4.2 pie chart and having multiple records in my store.
 i want to show legend color same as of the each slice color. currently each legend color is same in my production version but in my development version this is working correct. here is my code.

development snapshot

[image: development snapshot]

production snapshot

[image: production snapshot]

```
{
        xtype: 'piechartattendancereport',
        itemId: 'studentattandencesummeryvise',
        title: 'Attendance Summary',
        width : 450,
        minHeight : 240,
        store: 'mystore.store.attendance.PendingAttendanceGridStore',
        countField: 'totalDays',
        valueField: 'programName'
    }




Ext.define('myapp.view.PieChartAttendanceReport', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
    alias: 'widget.piechartattendancereport',
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    legend: {
        position: 'right'
    },
    insetPadding: 30,
    theme: 'Base:gradients',
    initComponent: function() {
        var this$ = this;
        var countField = !isNullOrEmpty(this.countField)?this.countField:'number';
        var valueField = !isNullOrEmpty(this.valueField)?this.valueField:'category';
        var showLegend = (!isNullOrEmpty(this.legendField)&& this.legendField)?true:false;
        var chartStore = null;
        if(!isNullOrEmpty(this.store)){
            chartStore = Ext.create(this.store);
        }else{
            chartStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore',{
                fields: ['number', 'category'],
                data: [{
                    number :0,
                    category : 'Category'
                }]
            });
        }
        Ext.apply(this$, {
            store: chartStore,
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                field: countField,
                showInLegend: true,
                donut: false,
                tips: {
                    trackMouse: true,
                    //width: 300,
                    height: 28,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                        var total = 0;
                        chartStore.each(function(rec) {
                            total += rec.get(countField);
                        });
                        var tipTitle = storeItem.get(valueField) + ': ' + storeItem.get(countField);
                        var length = (tipTitle.length)* 10;
                        this.setWidth(length);
                        this.setTitle(tipTitle);
                    }
                },
                highlight: {
                    segment: {
                        margin: 20
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    field: valueField,
                    display: 'rotate',
                    contrast: true,
                    font: '15px Arial',
                    renderer: function(value, label, storeItem, item, i, display, animate, index) {
                        var text;
                        if(storeItem.get(countField)!= undefined ||  storeItem.get(countField)!= null){
                            if(storeItem.get(countField) == 0){
                                text = '';
                            }else{
                                text = storeItem.get("Present")+ '%' ;
                                if(text.length > 12){
                                    text = text.substring(0, 10) + '..';
                                }
                            }

                        }else{
                            text = value;
                        }
                        label.setAttributes({
                            text: text
                        }, true);
                        return text;
                    }
                }
            }]
        });

        this$.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. Can you please provide fiddle for same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `label.setAttributes` to

```
label.setAttribute('text': text);
```

Because third parameter `avoidCopy` has a note that the content of object may be destroyed.

Also it can be a result of JS error, try to check console logs. I would suggest to use `typeof` instead of comparing with undefined:

```
if (typeof storeItem.get(countField) !== 'undefined' ||  storeItem.get(countField) != null) {
```

Comment: Thanks @FieryCat it is working for me